Clearing cache on submit of a Wordpress CF7 form
I have a Wordpress site using CF7, Dynamic text plugin and ACF. I send a user an email containing a URL that when clicked opens up a custom post type specific to that user. The post has a CF7 form on it and when the user clicks submit I have a function that updates the post category to 'private' and alters a status field from 'open' to closed'.
The category 'private' is locked to just admin users with UM Members.
When the user clicks the email the post type single.php has code to check if the form loaded is 'open' and 'public'.  Idea being that if it has already been submitted then the status would be 'private' and 'closed'.
This all works (status changes etc) but unless i manually clear the cache, after the user has submitted, the url still takes the user to a 'live' form to edit and they can resubmit data (not what i want).
I've trawled for some direction and I think I either have ot clear the cache on submit (which I'm not sure is possible) OR somehow stop the page caching in the first place? I'm guessing at this point.
Edit in response to comments: I use a caching plugin with Wordpress and I have to manually clear the cache for all pages in order for the front end user experience behave as I want it.  I’m not sure if this is a core Wordpress cache or browser cache so I guess the question is how do I clear both to be certain (or at least be able to test clearing both individually to figure out which one is causing the issue - assuming the cache is the issue).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

edit your question to explain if you speak about the cache of the browser, of the web host, of a plugin, of wordpress core ?

Updated based on comments
